# Graphic Layout of a special iOS object

Tags: ios

I would like to build an iPhone/iPad View with a circle like a compass. There should be the ability to touch inside the circle. Then from the middle of the circle a line will be drawn to the point you touched. I like to measure the length and angle of this line.

Is there a library I should learn and use for this like Cocos2D?

Comment: No, you can do this using normal Apple-provided classes.  You need to learn about touch events and a bit of trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just want to tie into touch events. When someone touches down on the screen, **detect where they have touched**, and compare this with what you have determined to be the center point you want to measure from (helpful to the user if this center point is shown visibly). After that, it's simple math to determine the angle and length. Length will be in the resolution of the screen though, so you will need to convert it to whatever unit of measure you desire.

Here's the code for finding the touch point, everything else should be pretty straight forward:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];
}
```